# Active Model Serializers data attributes from associations are not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, json-api

I am trying to load the association as follows:

This is my controller which is trying to render the json.

```
#app/controllers/store/products_controller.rb
  def customize
    @option_types = OptionType.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @option_types}
    end
  end
```

This is the serializer for above object

```
#app/serializers/option_type_serializer.rb
class OptionTypeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :key, :customizable, :name
  has_many :option_values
end
```

option_value `belong_to` option_type

```
#app/serializers/option_value_serializer.rb
class OptionValueSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :key, :option_type_id, :percentage_price_impact, :fixed_price_impact, :absolute_price_impact, :name
end
```

This is generating the following JSON. Although a number of other params are specified in the option_value_serializer.rb, only id and type appear in the generated JSON

```
// http://0.0.0.0:3000/products/810/customize.json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "option-types",
      "attributes": {
        "key": "fabric",
        "customizable": true,
        "name": "FABRIC"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "option-values": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "type": "option-values"
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "type": "option-values"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "option-types",
      "attributes": {
        "key": "cuff-type",
        "customizable": false,
        "name": "CUFF TYPE"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "option-values": {
          "data": [

          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "option-types",
      "attributes": {
        "key": "vents",
        "customizable": false,
        "name": "VENTS"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "option-values": {
          "data": [

          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forget the associations, do it this way:

```
#app/serializers/option_type_serializer.rb
class OptionTypeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :key, :customizable, :name, :option_values
  # has_many :option_values

  def option_values
    object.option_values.collect do |ov|
      {
          id: ov.id,
          key: ov.key,
          option_type_id: ov.option_type_id,
          percentage_price_impact: ov.percentage_price_impact,
          fixed_price_impact: ov.fixed_price_impact,
          absolute_price_impact: ov.absolute_price_impact,
          name: ov.name,
          description: ov.description,
          image: ov.option_image
      }
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer below is correct another approach could be like this:

```
class OptionTypeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :key, :customizable, :name, :option_values
  # has_many :option_values

  def option_values
    object.option_values.collect do |ov|
      OptionValueSerializer.new(ov)
    end
  end

end
```

By using this way you don't need to create object manually you can include decorators in `OptionValueSerializer` or include more relationship if you have nested one.

Hope this helps.